# What is the difference between getx and riverpod?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-getx, flutter-riverpod

I want to know what is the difference between getx and riverpod. I am so confused about which one of these two state management tools I will use in real projects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good and very recent YouTube video on the topic:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxkhUYC5yF8

However, I suggest you to look at BLoC and especially using its cubits.

Riverpod in my opinion is not a good choice since they decided to completely reinvent the wheel, not using InheritedWidget but instead implementing their own solution. I would never want to be working against a framework, but rather with it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that Riverpod follows unidirectional data flow and getx doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

go for riverpod for large products,
go for GetX for small applications.

GetX is not just a state managing tool, it more like a framework for flutter. If you only want a state manager you will get all of these extra functions and utilities you don’t need. And if you use all of what GetX have to offer, your entire routing, materialApp, localization, api, etc is dependent on one package. Having your application dependent on both Flutter and GetX to be maintained is an unnecessary gamble imo. Especially if it’s a production app.